# memory sharing in .o file

Tags: c, memory, compiler-construction, linker

Lets say i have a `A.c` file and compile it to a  `A.o` file.
The `A.c` file is as follows:

```
int a;
void add(void)
{
}
```

The `A.o` file together with a `B.o` form a `1.exe` file.
The `A.o` file together with a `C.o` form a `2.exe` file.

My question if I run `1.exe` and `2.exe` at the same time, will the address of `a` and `add()` be the same for these two `.exe` file? In another word, are there two `A.o` in the memory or there is only one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any relocated object files in memory.

<sup>I am guessing you have a Linux system. If on Windows, the principles remain the same, but the details are different.</sup>

The linker (called to build both `1.exe` and `2.exe`) build an executable [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) file (made of several segments, notably the so called ["text" segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_segment) for machine code and read-only constant data, and the ["data" segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) for mutable data). The [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall starting that program is memory mapping several segments of the ELF file (nearly as would some `mmap(2)` syscall).

<sup>Notice that using `.exe` file suffix for Linux executable files is confusing and uncommon. Conventionally, Linux executables have no suffix at all and start with a lowercase letter.</sup>

The linker has copied and relocated both `A.o` files into different things (because of the [relocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_%28computer_science%29)). So it usually happens that the address of `a` or `add` is different in `1.exe` and in `2.exe`, and so are the machine instructions dealing with them.

Each [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) has its own [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) (which can change with e.g. [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) syscall). Type `cat /proc/1234/maps` to understand the address space of process of pid 1234. Try also `cat /proc/self/maps` to get the address space of the process running that `cat`.

If instead of `A.o` object you have a *shared object* (or dynamic library) `libA.so` some of its (`mmap`-ed) segments will be shared (and others would be using [copy on write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_on_write) techniques), and some relocation happens at dynamic link time (e.g. during `dlopen` if it is a plugin).

Read also [Levine's book on *Linkers and Loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/).

Comment: Why are you using the .exe suffix?

Comment: Because the original poster used `.exe` suffix

Comment: Ah, then the OP probably used GCC on Windows, and all your stuff about `mmap` and ELF is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The addresses of `a` and `add` will not be the same. You have two processes, therefore two copies in memory in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on linking....by default linking is always dynamic so when u load two exe files into memory the file A.o will behave as reentrant function and its only one instance will be in memory which is shared by those two exe file...

its like printf function...there are so many printf any diff diff files but at a time only one instance is running in memory...

reentrant functions should not deliver any data corruption that u must take care of